# Como mostrar en un select de una view el nombre en lugar del id del modelo en ASP .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp, visual-studio-2019

Tengo un modelo factura relacionado de 1 a 1 con el modelo Clientes. Cuando voy a crear una factura se me carga en un select los clientes q tengo creados pero se cargan los id de estos clientes en lugar del nombre. Como puedo cambiar eso?
Mi vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su atencion

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Lee la documentación del constructor del [SelectList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_System_Object_). Tu error está en el `"ID", "ID"`

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas una SelectList, el tercer parámetro es la propiedad de tu lista de donde sacará el texto a mostrar. En tu caso necesitas definir que propiedad es la que quieres que use como texto para tu 'select'

```
ViewData["ClientesID"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Servicios>(), "ID", "Aqui_el_nombre_de_la_propiedad", facturas.ClientesID);
```